# I also want to see the count of zero

Tags: mysql

I also want to show the count of zero in this sql.

```sql
    SELECT diaries.id, emotion_id, image_url, color, summary, public, is_completed, diaries.created_at, diaries.is_deleted, likes.is_deleted, users.nickname, likes.diary_id, COUNT(likes.user_id) AS cnt FROM diaries
    INNER JOIN emotions ON diaries.emotion_id = emotions.id
    INNER JOIN users ON diaries.user_id = users.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON diaries.id = likes.diary_id
    WHERE diaries.is_deleted = 0 AND public = 1 AND is_completed = 1 AND likes.is_deleted = 0
    GROUP BY diary_id
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

I also want to see the count of zero.....

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. For further help, please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

The where clause cannot include any fields from the table that you use LEFT JOIN on.  This causes the LEFT JOIN to convert into an INNER JOIN.

You need to move this clause into the LEFT JOIN statement:

```
AND likes.is_deleted = 0
```

This will then return a COUNT(likes = 0)